# Passing Multidimensional Arrays to a function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to modify a multidimensional array. This is my function code -

```
void rot90(int n,char **a)
{
  int i,j;
  int b[n][n];

  for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
      a[n-1-i][j]=b[j][i];
    }
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
      a[i][j]=b[i][j];
    }  
  }
}
```

And in my main function , I am calling it as - 
A is a 2d Array nxn. 
    rot90(n,A);

which shows the following error on compilation - 
 warning: passing argument 2 of ‘rot90’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’

what is the right way to do it? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `A` ?

Comment: I suppose this is just an example reproducing the problem, but still: you are using `b` uninitialized here. At least `memset` it to zeros, or add a comment, or something, to avoid comments about UB :-)

Comment: you are passing pointer to the function but expects pointer to pointer

Comment: Try with `rot90(n,(char **)A);`.

Comment: Change `void rot90(int n,char **a)` to `void rot90(int n,char a[][10])`

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is an `N`x`N` array, and you're using a VLA (which it looks like from your snippet), then the prototype needs to be either

```
 void rot90( int n, char (*a)[n] )
```

or

```
 void rot90( int n, char a[][n] )
```

or

```
 void rot90( int n, char a[n][n] )
```

The second two forms are interpreted the same as the first; `a` is a pointer to an `n`-element array of `char`.